# How does a bool type in a dataframe and?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

A bool type dataframe:

```
m = df_device_commission[['X']].gt(0).any(axis=1)

print(m)

0      True
1      True
2      True
3     False
4      True
dtype: bool
```

another bool type dataframe:

```
n = df_device_commission[['Y']].notna().any(axis=1)

print(n)

0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4      True
dtype: bool
```

If I want to m and n, How should I write the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.logical_and`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html):

```
In [377]: import numpy as np

In [378]: np.logical_and(m,n)
Out[378]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: It's OK. Thanks vey much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `&` operator.

```py
>>> m & n

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: It's OK, thanks very much.